# Temporal evolution of a globally hyperbolic spacetime

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, differential-equations, physics, general-relativity, lorentzian-geometry

Any globally hyperbolic spacetime can be assigned a global function of time as Hawking has demonstrated for stably causal spacetime. (Any globally hyperbolic spacetime is also stably causal).

For Simplicity assume that there's no matter $T_{\mu\nu} =0$. And the spacetime satisfies Einstein's Field Equations.

Given a Cauchy hypersurface $S$ at initial time $t=t_0$,

**the main question is**:

*Can there exist any solution where the evolution of at least a single point $p \in S$ is smooth BUT ***nowhere analytic in time***?*

The initial data is that of the [Cauchy data](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_problem) and $S$ is supposed to be [spacelike](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0306108).

**Assume** $p \in U \subsetneq S$ where $U$ is an open subset of $S$ for the initial data set.

In case $U$ should not be even dense in $M$ or fulfill any other topological constraints, it must be clarified.

---

Physical motivation for the **interested reader**:

A smooth but no-where analytic evolution function for a Cauchy well-posed problem is my personal way to formulate **indeterminism**.

Comment: The question is ill-posed as written. Evolution with respect to which PDE? When speaking of regularity, at least two things must be defined precisely: "regularity" of initial data and "regularity" of solutions. Only in relating the two can the "regularity" of evolution be meaningfully discussed.

Comment: Isn't it just too obvious that the PDE is Einstein's Field Equation for a generally globally hyperbolic spacetime as much as the OP is concerned with? @IgorKhavkine

Comment: Is there a coordinate-free definition of what it means for a solution of the EFE to be analytic?

Comment: I guess as much as there is smoothness, why not analyticity? Though for a deeper response I should honestly think more. @JamesHanson

Comment: @BastamTajik My point is just that by intentionally choosing your coordinate system poorly, you can make any metric look non-analytic. Conversely, it's not prima facie clear to me that there even is a pseudo-Riemannian manifold that doesn't admit a coordinate system in which the metric is analytic (although I suspect there is).

Comment: Again at this moment, I can only say that $F$ in the Cauchy data, can be a non-analytic function of the Cauchy surface neighbourhood derivatives as a functional regardless of the derivatives dependence on the coordinates. I mean temporal derivatives of $u$ as a functional of $\phi$. Tomorrow I'll give a more sensible reply. Sorry and thanks. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_problem

Comment: Its subsequent theorem "Cauchy–Kowalevski theorem" might help us see eye to eye. Nonetheless thanks for commenting. I'll think more.

Comment: @BastamTajik since you are the OP, what they are concerned with might be clear to you, but not necessarily to the rest of us. Anyway, the edits don't actually address the core remarks from the comments by James Hanson and myself. In addition, if you haven't noticed, what comes after "Said differently..." is not actually equivalent to the first question. I'm voting to close, unless the OP is able to rephrase the question in a mathematically meaningful way.

Comment: JamesHanson is to be dealt with me. The answer to your first comment is already clear. I don't get your comment on the second part. Nonetheless I remove "said differently". Maybe there's a forest beyond the tree! The questions are to be edited and reviewed as far as the OP is responsible for the objections before voting for closure, from a professional ethical point of view. Though you are the people of research business, and I am just a master's student! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Kovalevskaya_theorem
@IgorKhavkine

Comment: @JamesHanson after all a smooth manifold can either admit an analytic diff structure or not(no intuitionism).The question would be if there are manifolds that have transition functions that are nowhere analytic but everywhere smooth? The metric to me is: $g∈Γ(TM⊗TM)^∗$
 and its analyticity should be questioned as a section of $(TM⊗TM)^∗$
 which is a map between the two manifolds $M$
 and $TM^∗⊗TM^∗$
 whose analyticity might be related to the analytic extension of the already assumed smooth structure over $M$
. This the Riemannian case and coordinate independent. I will update for the P-R.

Comment: @BastamTajik - is chapter XII of Choquet-Bruhat's book _General Relativity and Einstein's Equations_  of any assistance in reformulating your question?  I ask because sub-section 12 of that chapter provides global existence and uniqueness theorems.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in chaos in the context of general relativity and quantum gravity, this Q&A may be helpful - https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/369767/chaos-and-general-relativity

In particular, the first paper cited there, John D. Barrow *Chaotic Behaviour in General Relativity* Physics Reports 85(1) 1982 pp. 1-49 https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-1573(82)90171-5 may help in resolving your original question.

ETA: For further historical background on existence theory for the non-analytic case, it's useful to consult

Demetrios Christodoulou and Richard Kerner *Editorial note to: Existence theorem for the Einsteinian gravitational field equations in the non-analytic case, by Yvonne Fourès-Bruhat*,
Gen Relativ Gravit **54**, 36 (2022). https://doi.org/10.1007/s10714-022-02916-5